# Android - Hide first activity before parseloginui

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am starting to study Parse with Android, and i found ParseLoginUI, but i am having some problems, when I am using ParseLoginUI Dispatcher, one empty screen open before starts login screen,how can i do to hide this, please?!

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.appstudy"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".AppApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity" /* dispatcher */
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity.PARSE_LOGIN_ENABLED"
                android:value="true" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity.PARSE_LOGIN_EMAIL_AS_USERNAME"
                android:value="true" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.parse.ui.ParseLoginActivity.FACEBOOK_LOGIN_ENABLED"
                android:value="true" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" />

        <meta-data

MainActivity (dispatcher)

    public class MainActivity extends ParseLoginDispatchActivity {    
    @Override    
        protected Class<?> getTargetClass() {    
            return AppActivity.class;    
        }    
    }    
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name=".AppActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_app"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity (dispatcher)

```
package br.com.dietshare;

import com.parse.ui.ParseLoginDispatchActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ParseLoginDispatchActivity {

    @Override
    protected Class<?> getTargetClass() {
        return DietActivity.class;
    }

}
```

Best Regards,
Rodrigo

Comment: hello, were you able to solve this issue?